# Is it possible to use Javascript to "hover" over links?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a webpage which uses a third-party javascript library to pull JSONP data from their API, and then builds a rich tooltip based on the data returned... when the visitor hovers their mouse cursor over the link.

Is it possible to use javascript to mimic the mouse hover state? (so the rich tooltip appears permanently)

**Update for more info**

The [javascript is from WoWHead here](http://www.wowhead.com/tooltips). It runs automatically after it's loaded, searching the DOM for wowhead.com links and building tooltips dynamically on mouse hover.

Essentially, I'd like the dynamically generated tooltip always visible, rather than only on hover.

Comment: You might have to get a little more specific, here.  Are you looking for something that you can simulate the same functionality with, like an event-listener which then permanently "turns-on" similar functionality, or calls the function that builds the tooltip, which you then personally "unhide" and position on the page...***OR*** are you looking for something that permanently spoofs `:hover` on an element?  If it's the second one, you're probably out o' luck.  And that's a good thing, because browsers are single-threaded.  If you fired off a call every 1ms to make it hover, you'd chug like mad

Comment: Why don't you just put the logic that shows the tooltip into a function that you can call in the hover event and in any other case you want?

Comment: updated question with more info

Answer (score 0):

You might need to post the code that does the tooltip for a better answer, but can't you just take it out of the "onmousehover" and just have it run on page load?